# How do I use built-in PhpStorm webserver when I have remote hosts also configured?

Tags: php, phpstorm

I had the built-in webserver configured for my PhpStorm project, so that "Open in Browser" loaded the file via localhost. I then configured a remote host via SFTP so that I could test and sync things in the final environment, but now my "Open in Browser" opens the remote web address and I can't find how to open local copies now.

I tried creating a new "Remote host" with Type "Local or mounted folder" or "In place" and set the URL to `http://localhost:63342/`. The server is running, but I get 404 errors, even when manually navigation to `http://localhost:63342/<projectname>/folder/file.php`

Am I missing something stupid? Are there some docs for mixing local debugging and remote hosts?

Comment: Will it work again if you unmark that SFTP deployment entry as Default for the project?

Comment: D'oh! Didn't realise I could go back to no default. Un-defaulting my local and going back to no default at all restored the built-in server. @LazyOne - please submit as an answer so I can tick it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try unmarking your SFTP Deployment entry as Default for this project. With no default set the built-in server will be used by default.

---

> but I get 404 errors, even when manually navigation to `http://localhost:63342/<projectname>/folder/file.php`

This should not be happening -- the built-in web server should be always available. At least I could not reproduce such issue when doing *quick test* locally in 8.0.2.

But if it's reproducible for you then I may only advise to submit new ticket to their [Issue Tracker](https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issues/WI).